# Initializing H2O with RStudio on Windows

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, h2o

I am new to H2O and am having some trouble initializing H2O in RStudio (R 3.2 version in 64-bit Windows 7) to do tax fraud predictive modelling. The steps I made to start H2O where the following:

1. I installed H2O latest stable release ("Noether 2.8.4.4" from (http://0xdata.com/download/)
2. I launched H2O from my terminal after unzipping using:

`cd Downloads
 cd h2o-2.8.4.4
 java -jar h2o.jar`

3. I pointed to H2O URL in Google Chrome: http://localhost:54321/
4. Run the script in Rstudio to start with the demo:

`library(h2o,lib.loc="C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.1.2/library")
 localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE)`

But after this fourth step I received the following message:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\AMARTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1aKXp/h2o_amartinezsistac_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\AMARTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1aKXp/h2o_amartinezsistac_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
Error in h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE) : 
      H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```

I would appreciate any help or advice on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Firewall issue? Antivirus issue?

Comment: Hello Pascal. This could be probably a good reason as there is actually a Firewall in the company I work for. I will test it in another place to discard this.

Comment: Your description of the problem doesn't say explicitly, but is this an R or Rstudio issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of your problem is that you should define ip. So try something like this

```
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "enter your ip-address", port = 54321, startH2O = F)
```